# Any way to export layers to files WITHOUT a prefix, short of editing the .jsx file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, automation, script, regex

[image: Bridge Batch Rename Screenshot]I'm using a template PSD to crop large batches of ecom images and then exporting my layers to TIFF files. Only problem is Photoshop insists on putting a prefix in front of each file name--even if I leave that field blank it autofills it starting with *0000*. It's impossible to batch rename them after the fact because they all have unique style numbers, and going back through and deleting the prefix is incredibly annoying when it's a large group of images.

I have seen advice online saying to delete a line of code from the Layers To Files script, but I don't seem to be able to do that because I'm on a work computer and those files are locked.

Is there any way around this, or is there an alternative method I can use to batch export layers to TIFF files that will use the layer name as the file name?

Comment: Can you include the script?

Answer (score 3):

If you have Adobe Bridge that makes it very easy to batch rename the files using **Batch Rename** and some REGEX.

Using **String Substitution** with REGEX this is what I would do:

> **Find:** `^_\d{4}_`
>
> **Replace:** leave blank

---

**Explanation:**
<sup>Courtesy of [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)</sup>

`^` asserts position at start of a line
`_` matches the character `_`
`\d` matches any digit equal to `0`-`9`
`{4}` **Quantifier** — Matches exactly 4 times
`_` matches the character `_`

**Results:**

[image: results]

Comment: The problem is that the prefix is sequenced (_0000_, _0001_, _0002_, etc), and I don't seem to be able to tell Bridge to just delete the first 6 characters. I'm not sure what ^\d{4} is, but I figured maybe that was a workaround to do exactly what I just said--so I tested it (^\d{6} in my case, for 6 characters), but it did not change anything.

Comment: `^` means the start of the string, `\d` means any numeric character (0-9) and `{4}` is a quantifier - how many times it's repeated.

Comment: @Sabina can you do it with `{6}` and then click on **Preview** and take a screenshot and upload that here?

Comment: @Sabina make sure you also selected the **Use Regular Expression** box when you entered that regex string.

Comment: Don't seem to be able to add pictures to comments, so I edited my original question to include a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: @Sabina I've updated my answer with the new regex, I hadn't realized there were underscores - to include that use `^_\d{4}_`

Comment: Thank you so much! I spoke to a friend about it also and he said to type "^.{0,6}". Both of these work, and I appreciate the explanation on what each of those characters signifies!